# How to fetch the data from the Google Analytics explore Form

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I want to fetch my Google Analytics report to my local through an api.

I have created a Report in Google Analytics explore : this image.

[image]

Here I can download the csv which I want to read the data in my local through the csv.

Now for that I am trying to follow this document :

[Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)

Which I am not sure this is correct approach or not. Also got stuck on some point like

1. I have downloaded Credentials.json where not sure what to change in client_email.
2. What is the best approach to achieve that. Any programming language is fine.  Can anybody help me here to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

That api you're using is called the `Reporting API` or the `Data API` as they've remarketed it for GA4. And generally, it would be a good practice to use it and there are plenty of libraries and examples of its usage in multiple languages, including Python, [here](https://github.com/practical-data-science/gapandas4) is a good example. I'd suggest either going with a third party article detailling the setup process, or even just using a third party library that can abstract a lot of roughness Google introduced in the API.

But that api is new, and the product, overall, is effectively just a beta with quite a number of bugs and documentation holes. There's a simpler way to get the data out. First, [link the GA4 property to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). This will effectively set up daily (or streaming) exports to BQ.

Once the data is in BQ, you're able to see the raw data and understand it way better than in GA4 explorer. From there, it will be much easier for you to export the data to your local from BQ. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) is a library that could be handy. Having the raw data in BQ makes it way easier to debug your data reports.

Comment: @BNaxaruk thanks for the answers. As i want to know that will they give the data for the exact view which i have created for explorer view.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Although it would be comfy. I guess, you could try bruteforcing it by making a bot that logs in to your GA account and then goes to your Explorer report, then downloads and parses the report csv. But only in theory. I haven't seen anyone going through all this trouble just to avoid doing it the intended way.